# useContext from different files without export

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-context

I have a react app with a bunch of state

```
function App(){
 const [activeChoice, setActiveChoice] = useState("flights");
 const [overlay, setOverlay] = useState(false);
 const [airports, setAirports] = useState<Airport[]>([]);
 const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

 const GlobalState = {
      loading,
      airports,
 };
 const MainContext = createContext(GlobalState);
 return(
   //Some code
  );
}
```

**Problem** I create context to share data across my application. I cant export it like this

```
export const MainContext = createContext(GlobalState);
```

because `MainContext` is inside the App function and i get an error *Modifiers cannot appear here.*

If i create the context outside the **App** function. I cant reference the **GlobalState** object because it is inside the App function. Remember **GlobalState** has state properties that cant be created outside the React component.

I also cant use the createContext function without passing the default value (TypeScript).So i have to pass that **GlobalState** object. If i try using it empty i get an error *n argument for 'defaultValue' was not provided.*

I want to **useContext** inside another component in a different file . I have wrapped the child component with the provider as necessary but in the other component i dont know how to get the context so as to do this.

```
const {airports} = useContext(MainContext);
```

Comment: If you're dealing with complex global state, I'd recommend investigating https://redux.js.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> MainContext is inside the App function

You can't do that. Not only does it make it impossible to export, but it also means that every time App rerenders, you're creating a brand new context. Not just new values on the existing context, a new type of context unrelated to the old one. So your MainContext.Provider will unmount, and a new one be created in its place. And even if you were somehow consuming the old one in a child component, it will lose that connection when the parent rerenders.

You need to define the context once, outside of App. Inside of app, you can fill out the value.

```
export const MainContext = createContext(); // We'll get to the types in a sec

function App(){
 const [activeChoice, setActiveChoice] = useState("flights");
 const [overlay, setOverlay] = useState(false);
 const [airports, setAirports] = useState<Airport[]>([]);
 const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

 const GlobalState = {
    loading,
    airports,
 };

 return(
    <MainContext.Provider value={GlobalState}>
     // some code
    </MainContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

> I also cant use the createContext function without passing the default value (TypeScript).

There are a few solutions to this. One is to just fill in a default value, with things like empty arrays where an array is required, or functions that do nothing (`() => {}`) where a function is required.

```
interface MainContextValue {
  loading: boolean,
  airports: Airport[]
}

export const MainContext = createContext<MainContextValue>({
  loading: false,
  airports: []
});
```

But that can be combersome for large contexts, and in most cases you don't intend for the default value to ever be used. So a second option is to give it a default value that's not technically correct for the type, but just shut typescript up with a type assertion:

```
export const MainContext = createContext<MainContextValue>(undefined as MainContextValue)
```

Another option is to set up the context so it can include undefined, but then when you access it, do so through a custom hook that will throw an error if it's undefined. This will exclude undefined from the type, but also show a relevant error message to remind you what needs to be fixed:

```
export const MainContext = createContext<MainContextValue | undefined>()

MainContext.displayName = 'Main'; // to help with debugging

// Elsewhere:
export function useContextThrowUndefined<T>(
  context: Context<T | undefined>
): T {
  const value = useContext(context);
  if (value === undefined) {
    const name = context.displayName ?? "";
    throw new Error(
      `${name} context consumer was used outside of a context provider.
To fix this, make sure the provider is always higher up the component tree than the consumer.
`);
  }
  return value;
}

// used like:
const SomeComponent = () => {
  const { airports } = useContextThrowUndefined(MainContext);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define the context outside with its default value to `null` or a default value that makes sense e.g. `{ loading: false, airports: [] }`.

Both can be typed as in the following code snippet.

```ts
export GlobalStateType {
  loading: boolean;
  airports: Airport[];
}

const MainContext = createContext<GlobalStateType | null>(null);

// or with empty state
const MainContext = createContext<GlobalStateType>({ loading: true, airports: [] });

function App(){
 const [activeChoice, setActiveChoice] = useState("flights");
 const [overlay, setOverlay] = useState(false);
 const [airports, setAirports] = useState<Airport[]>([]);
 const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

 const GlobalState: GlobalStateType = {
      loading,
      airports,
 };
 return(
    <MainContext.Provider value={GlobalState}>
    </MainContext.Provider>
  );
}
```